# Calculate minutes from string of minutes and hours

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function which takes a string of hours and minutes and convert it to minutes. this works absolutely fine but what if the received argument is only of minutes or hour. for example

```
const str = "1 hour 5 mins"; // works
const str = "1 hour"; // doesn't work
const str = "5 mins"; //  doesn't work

const str = "1 hour 5 mins";
this.calculate(str);
calculate(str) {
    let res = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
    return res[0] * 60 + res[1]
}
```

Comment: It's working for me : i obtain `65`.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ it doesn't work for the others, but works for `1 hour 5 mins`

Comment: `return ((res.lenght>1)?res[0] * 60 + res[1] : res[0] * 60);`

Comment: `let res = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);`  this statement only matches once, there is no 2nd digit, so fails

Comment: Match `(\d+)\s*(\w+)` and inspect that second `\w` more closely for its value…

Comment: @Nuwan94 that doesn't work for the third example

Comment: @Hardik How do you use that to distinguish `1 hour` from `5 mins`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a smarter regular expression that is able to distinguish between hour and minute values:

```js
const calculate = (s) => {
  const matches = /(?:(\d+) hours?)? ?(?:(\d+) mins?)?/.exec(s);
  
  return Number(matches[1] || 0) * 60 + Number(matches[2] || 0);
};

console.log(calculate('1 hour 5 mins')); // 65
console.log(calculate('2 hours 1 min')); // 121
console.log(calculate('3 hours')); // 180
console.log(calculate('10 mins')); // 10
```

Comment: can you explain what goes here?

Answer (score 3):

You can check that if your string contains `hour` then first value need to multiply with `60` else it should be use same value.

And `(res[0] || 0)` this part will return value `0` when `res[0]` is `null` or `undefined`.

```js
function calculate(str) {
  let multiplier = str.includes("hour") ? 60 : 1;
  let res = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
  return (res[0] || 0) * multiplier + (res[1] || 0);
}

console.log(this.calculate("1 hour 5 mins"));
console.log(this.calculate("1 hour"));
console.log(this.calculate("5 mins"));
console.log(this.calculate("2 hours 5 mins"));
```

Comment: what if it is console.log(this.calculate("2 hours 5 mins"));

Comment: Thanks man, I worry that I could not accept more than one answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you look for the specific terms and pull out a number/unit pair you can use capture groups to do the calculations.

```js
const t1 = '1 hour 5 mins';
const t2 = '1 hour';
const t3 = '5 mins';
const t4 = '2 hours 1 min';

const parseDuration = (s) => {
  var matches = s.match(/(\d+\s?hours?)?\s?(\d+\s?mins?)?/);
  var total = matches[1] ? parseInt(matches[1])*60 : 0;
  total += matches[2] ? parseInt(matches[2]) : 0;
  return total;
}

console.log(parseDuration(t1));
console.log(parseDuration(t2));
console.log(parseDuration(t3));
console.log(parseDuration(t4));
```

Comment: @saila don't worry about it

Comment: console.log(calculate('2 hours 1 min'));// doesn't work yet

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.